# How do I frame this question?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, editing, structure

I'm writing a script and there's a question I want one character to ask another but for nearly a month, I just can't construct the question even though I know what I want to ask.
Basically, I want to ask "what part of the body is to blame for sin?", as in, what causes sin to happen. but that doesn't sound good to me, so I thought maybe "what is the origin of sin?" But then my answer to that doesn't make sense.
My answer is basically "The head, vessel of all impure thoughts that culminates into sin".

Can someone help frame this question better? I'd be elated

Comment: I'd like some clarification regarding the purpose of the question. Is the character asking it as a riddle or is it simply a moral question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, one of these'll work.

1. From where does sin spring from?
2. What place is to blame for sin?
3. What houses sin?
4. In what house/place does sin dwell?
5. Where is sin birthed?
6. What is the crucible of sin?

Hope this helps!